# How to add vertical scrollbar to select box options list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need vertical scrollbar for select box options list. I have to show only first few items of the list. I don't have any control over number of items in the list.

I have checked all similar questions here and nothing worked out. Anyway to do that?

```css
.wrapper{
width:200px;
padding:20px;
height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="wrapper" ><select name="" id="" class="form-control">
        <option value="">One</option>
        <option value="">Two</option>
        <option value="">Three</option>
        <option value="">Four</option>
        <option value="">Five</option>
        <option value="">Six</option>
        <option value="">Seven</option>
        <option value="">Eight</option>
        <option value="">Nine</option>
        <option value="">Ten</option>
    </select></div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Overflow-y` doesn't work on select boxes.  What I would recommend using is `size` on your select box. In my example I've used 5 as the value, you can obviously change this to your liking.

```css
.wrapper{
width:200px;
padding:20px;
height: 150px;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    
    <div class="wrapper"><select name="" id="" class="form-control" onfocus='this.size=5;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
    <option value="">One</option>
    <option value="">Two</option>
    <option value="">Three</option>
    <option value="">Four</option>
    <option value="">Five</option>
    <option value="">Six</option>
    <option value="">Seven</option>
    <option value="">Eight</option>
    <option value="">Nine</option>
    <option value="">Ten</option>
</select></div>
```

**Edit:** Amended my answer to include some js to provide OP with the desired result.

Comment: adding size attribute makes it it like multiselect box. I want to keep select box default styling..Only that dropdown list should have that scrollbar

Comment: @NareshShetty changed my answer to give you what you need.  Can't think of any other way of doing this. :)

Comment: This causes reflow of whole page when select changes height.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this (Replace the number 3 with the number of items you would like to show):

```html
    <select onfocus='this.size=3;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: OnFocus also I dont wan't to change select box default behaviour. I want only that option list to have scrollbar, Not for select Box

Comment: That is the only way for the select box to have this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just add size attribute in your select. For ex:- size="5"

```css
.wrapper{
width:200px;
padding:20px;
height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="wrapper" >
<select size="5" name="" id="" class="form-control">
        <option value="">One</option>
        <option value="">Two</option>
        <option value="">Three</option>
        <option value="">Four</option>
        <option value="">Five</option>
        <option value="">Six</option>
        <option value="">Seven</option>
        <option value="">Eight</option>
        <option value="">Nine</option>
        <option value="">Ten</option>
    </select></div>
```

Comment: adding size attribute makes it like multiselect box. I want to keep select box default styling..Only that dropdown list should have that scrollbar

Comment: Then you can use select2 writen in jquery which is same like select and also you can specify scroll also. https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Answer (score 1):

You can just give size , it will work somehow.

```
 <select size="5">
 // all your option comes here
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below select configuration worked well for me.

```js
$("select").on("focus", function(){
    this.size = 5;
});

$("select").on("change", function(){
    this.blur();
});

$("select").on("blur", function(){
    this.size = 1;
    this.blur();
});
```

```css
select{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 30% !important;
}
```

```html
<h4>Use the below select config along with the css and js provided</h4>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select size="1" onfocus="this.size = 8" onchange="this.blur()" onblur="this.size = 1; this.blur()">
    <option selected>--Select--</option>
    <option value="">One</option>
    <option value="">Two</option>
    <option value="">Three</option>
    <option value="">Four</option>
    <option value="">Five</option>
    <option value="">Six</option>
    <option value="">Seven</option>
    <option value="">Eight</option>
    <option value="">Nine</option>
    <option value="">Ten</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).