# Scrollable list of clickable items

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I'm trying to implement a scrolling list of clickable items, where the amount of items will vary depending on which array of items is selected before being redirected to the html page. Is there a built in way or some free to use JS code to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Welcome to SO , please read on how to ask a Q in SO (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  .... refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560072/how-to-add-vertical-scrollbar-to-select-box-options-list/48560262

Comment: @MarkOrmesher I Was suggesting same :) one step away from googling

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for. Thanks for the tips, new to SO :)