# How can I make my dropdown scrollable with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, angular

I'm attempting to make a dropdown list within my reactive form, but there's no option available to make my dropdown scrollable when the item list exceeds the page size. I tried using max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; on the given elements and tinkered with giving them classes, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<select class="form-control" [formControl]="modalForm.get('album')">
  <option selected>Select album...</option>
  <option 
     *ngFor="let album of albums"
     [value]="album.name">{{ album.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Anyone else experience this problem with bootstrap?

Comment: Hope you have given max-height to the `select` element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560072/how-to-add-vertical-scrollbar-to-select-box-options-list

Comment: I gave the max-height to the select element, but it didn't affect it. That previous forum that you linked me to did give me a work around... but I was also hoping to keep the default select behavior of a drop down list other then a menu selection box - which is what that code gives me. Was hoping to simply add a scroll bar to the default select drop down if it was possible.