is there a way to make <select> list box scrollable with a scroll bar?
i want it to look like this
i read this question on forum and answer to this was
`<select size="3">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>

although my data will be coming from a repository(database)
so how does that work ?
do i return size of the list for the size attribute?
is there another way?

You can take a look at this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560072/how-to-add-vertical-scrollbar-to-select-box-options-list
